# How to provide the index of the clicked button which is created dynamically by instance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

1. I am trying to pass the index of the clicked button in Repeat(int value) and wrote this -
       gp.GetComponentInChildren ().onClick.AddListener(() => 
       Repeat(rep));
2. But when I click any button I got the last index of the button for all.
   I want to know is there any way, I can pass the index of that button which i clicked in Repeat()?

```
void chatDialogs() {

        foreach (Transform child in this.transform) {
            GameObject.Destroy (child.gameObject);
        }

        for (int i = 5; i > 0 ; i--) {
            int currentStep = Laststep - i;
            if (currentStep >= 0) {
                 gp = (GameObject)Instantiate (playerPreFab);
                 gp.transform.SetParent (this.transform);
            }
            gp.GetComponentInChildren<Button> ().onClick.AddListener(() => 
            Repeat(**transform.GetSiblingIndex()**));
        }
    public void Repeat(int speakstep) {
        Application.ExternalCall("textspeak", speakstep);
    }
```

in speakstep object of Repeat() the clicked button index should be passed, but its getting the last index in every button I click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
AddButtonListener(gp.GetComponentInChildren<Button> (), i);
```

inside your `for` loop, 
when `AddButtonListener` is defined as:

```
void AddButtonListener(Button b, int index)
{
    b.onClick.AddListener(()=>{Repeat(index)});
}
```

This way you capture the button index in the listener function (but I'm not sure what the correct name of this pattern is), and I wrote this without actually running it. Hope you have enough info now to get it working.

Comment: Actually in my for loop I am instanciating only 5 elements rest are being destroyed. Hence I am not able to assign the actual index value of i in this line - AddButtonListener(gp.GetComponentInChildren<Button> (), i);

Comment: then do this: `b.onClick.AddListener(()=>{Repeat(b.transform.GetSiblingIndex())});` and remove the `index` parameter from `AddButtonListener`

Comment: By using this line - b.onClick.AddListener(()=>{Repeat(b.transform.GetSiblingIndex())});    I am getting the 0th index for all the buttons.